# material-ui / How to style an HOC using 'withStyles()'?

Tags: material-ui, jss

My HOC :

```js
const withPaper = Component => props => (
  <Paper>
    <Component {...props} />
  </Paper>
);

export default withPaper;
```

I want to style 'Paper' component using `withStyles()`:

```js
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: 'green'
  }
});

const withPaper = ?? => ?? => (
  <Paper className={classes.root}>
    <Component {...props} />
  </Paper>
);

export default withStyles(styles)(withPaper);
```

How can I inject classes prop this case? 
My simple idea `Component => ({classes, ...props}) =>` logs error.

> TypeError: Cannot call a class as a function

Answer (score 6):

Answering my own question.

I ignored the returns of HOC. It returns 'Component' instead of 'React Element'. 
I'm not sure, but I think this is the reason that I couldn't inject classes from outside of HOC.

My solution that works well - styling inside of HOC:

```js
const withPaper = Component => {
  const WithPaper = ({ classes, ...props }) => (
    <Paper className={classes.root}>
      <Component {...props} />
    </Paper>
  );

  const styles = theme => ({
    root: {
      backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
  });

  return withStyles(styles)(WithPaper);
};

export default withPaper;
```

FYI, TypeScript users can refer to Rahel's answer.

Answer (score 4):

I am in the process of learning Material-UI and TypeScript myself, and I was actually struggling with the very same thing :-) Apologies if you were looking for a JS solution, but the types being explicit might actually help:

```js
import * as React from "react";
import createStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/createStyles";
import { WithStyles } from "@material-ui/core";
import Paper from "@material-ui/core/Paper/Paper";
import { compose } from "recompose";
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles";

const styles = createStyles({
  root: {
    backgroundColor: "green"
  }
});

type WrapperProps = WithStyles<typeof styles>;

const withPaper = <P extends {}>(Component: React.ComponentType<P>) => {
  type Props = P & WrapperProps;

  return (props: Props) => {
    return (
      <Paper className={props.classes.root}>
        <Component {...props} />
      </Paper>
    );
  };
};

export default compose(withStyles(styles), withPaper);
```

[image: Edit xvkwo6vzxz]

Note the usage of [recompose](https://www.npmjs.com/package/recompose), to `compose` your higher-order components. If you mind this library-dependency, you can also do without:

```js
export default (component: React.ComponentType) => withStyles(styles)(withPaper(component));
```

Comment: Though I'm not familiar with TS, this would be quite helpful to those who use TS. Thanks, Rahel.